# Same template class friendship

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I would like to have all classes of the template to be friends, regardless of the types:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class A
{
  template <typename, typename> friend class A;

public:

  A() = default;

  template<typename... Args>
  A(const A<Args...>& o) : a(o.a), b(o.b), t1(), t2() {}

private:
  int a, b;
  T1 t1; 
  T2 t2;
};

int main()
{
  A<int, int> a;
  A<double, double> b(a);
}
```

Because the number of template parameters may change, it's not very convenient to write `typename, typename, typename`. I was wondering whether this could be changed to something similar to:

```
template <typename...> friend class A;
```

Having it in this form produces redeclaration errors.

Comment: That seems like too much friendly already.  I'd just change `class` to `struct` and let anyone-and-everyone be overly friendly.

Comment: Yes .. might by an X-Y problem, why do you need so much "friendliness"?

Comment: I've modified the example, to better illustrate. That's because I may have some common private member types, like a,b which I'd like to access in the copy constructor, for example.

Comment: `template <typename...> class` and `template <typename, typename> class` declare two different templates, so that won't work.

Comment: sorry, but imho the motivation is moot. If the number of argument changes then you need to change so much more and this line is your least problem (because its a nice compiler error). Is there anything beyond saving some typing that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, agree. But, let's say that I have 10 template params. How convenient is it to write `typename` 10 times?

Comment: 10 template arguments, just like 10 function arguments, is a design smell. I'd fix the design rather than try to find a hack for a more dense friend declaration.

Comment: True. Was just wondering if something like that can be done. Thanks.